# For the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, we define the norm function $f:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {d}] \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ by: $ f(a+b\sqrt d)=|a^2-db^2|$. How can I prove that $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$?

What I've got: Suppose $x=a+b\sqrt d$ and $f(x)=0$. Then $a^2=db^2$. How can I proceed from there?

Suppose $x=0$, how can I show that $a=b=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $d$ is not a square from $a^2=db^2$. Suppose $a,b\neq 0$ we have $d=a^2/b^2$. Impossible since this implies that $\sqrt d=a/b$ is rational. Thus $b=0$ and $a^2=a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $b\neq 0$, show that $db^2$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: Note: the property of $f$ in question only holds if $d$ is not a perfect square. I assume that this assumption is made implicitly.